# How to put Text on the top of page

Tags: javascript, arrays

this script works perfect. One problem though, when I post the blog, the Text goes under the already existing text. How would I make it be the first ontop and move all the others down?

```
 postBlog.onclick = function(){
            console.log("Someone wants to post a blogpost");
            console.log(document.getElementById("Texto").value);
            arrayData.push(document.getElementById("Texto").value);

            for (i=0; i < arrayData.length; i++){
                oldText = testbox.innerHTML;
                breakoo = "<br />";
                testbox.innerHTML = oldText + arrayData[i] +breakoo;
                 arrayData = [];
            }
        };
```

Comment: Have you tried putting `oldText` after `arrayData[i]`?

Comment: You're clearing `arrayData` in your loop, this means only the first element will get added.

Answer (score 1):

You simply do

```
 testbox.innerHTML = arrayData[i] + breakoo + oldText;
```

That's it

Answer (score 0):

Instead of push, you could use unshift.

```
arrayData.unshift(docoment.getElementById("Texto").value);
```

ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift

Answer (score 0):

You can use it with jQuery

```
$( ".inner" ).before( "<p>Test</p>" );
```

Comment: I don't see a jQuery tag on this question.